# How to print a thematic bibliography using multiple keywords?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have 1278 entries in a `.bib` file. I intend to put keywords to those entries so I can print thematic bibliography. But it seems is not working with multiple keywords, but only with one. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Splitting_into_different_topics) it is said that I can put multiple keywords so I assumed that I can print multiple keywords.

Here is the MWE trying to print book 1 & book 3.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{anania:greul,
 author = {Anania, Valeriu},
 year = {1982},
 title = {Greul pămîntului},
 publisher = {{Editura Eminescu}},
 series = {Teatru comentat},
 subtitle = {O pentalogie a mitului românesc},
 location = {București},
 keywords = {mitologie,anania}
}

@inbook{anania:greul:pol,
 author = {Anania, Valeriu},
 title = {Greul pământului},
 publisher = {Polirom},
 isbn = {978-973-46-1065-5},
 series = {Seria de autor Valeriu Anania},
 booktitle = {Teatru},
 year = {2008},
 volumes = {2},
 volume = {2},
 location = {Iași},
 note = {Cronologie de Ștefan Iloaie},
 keywords = {teatru, anania}
}

@book{anania:memorii,
 author = {Anania, Valeriu},
 year = {2011},
 title = {Memorii},
 publisher = {Polirom},
 isbn = {978-973-46-1175-1},
 location = {Iași},
 keywords = {memorii, societate}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={mitologie,societate},title={Carti}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyword` option only accepts a single keyword as argument. You could use several `keyword` options, but they would be joined with an AND, so would not show any of your references.

If you want to combine several `keyword`s with a logical OR, you need to define a bibliography filter

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\defbibfilter{mitologieORsocietate}{%
  keyword=mitologie
  or
  keyword=societate
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{anania:greul,
  author    = {Anania, Valeriu},
  year      = {1982},
  title     = {Greul pămîntului},
  publisher = {{Editura Eminescu}},
  series    = {Teatru comentat},
  subtitle  = {O pentalogie a mitului românesc},
  location  = {București},
  keywords  = {mitologie,anania}
}
@inbook{anania:greul:pol,
  author    = {Anania, Valeriu},
  title     = {Greul pământului},
  publisher = {Polirom},
  isbn      = {978-973-46-1065-5},
  series    = {Seria de autor Valeriu Anania},
  booktitle = {Teatru},
  year      = {2008},
  volumes   = {2},
  volume    = {2},
  location  = {Iași},
  note      = {Cronologie de Ștefan Iloaie},
  keywords  = {teatru, anania}
}
@book{anania:memorii,
  author    = {Anania, Valeriu},
  year      = {2011},
  title     = {Memorii},
  publisher = {Polirom},
  isbn      = {978-973-46-1175-1},
  location  = {Iași},
  keywords  = {memorii, societate}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[filter=mitologieORsocietate,title={Carti}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two entries.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I assume that I can declare more filters, right? The syntax is simple and even I can remember this even programming is not my field.

Comment: @Mafsi Yes, you can define several filters. The syntax is explained in §3.8.9 *Bibliography Filters and Checks* of the manual. You can only do high-level stuff with filters, if you want access to more options, you can use bibliography checks, which have a more complex syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the `keyword` option you are using is wrong. This a correct syntax but it prints only the entries with both keywords:

```
\printbibliography[keyword=memorii,keyword=societate]
```

For your purpose you should define a filter. For example, to print the entries with one of these keywords: `societate` or `mitologie` or `teatru`, you need:

```
\defbibfilter{example}{%
  keyword=societate or keyword=mitologie or keyword=teatru
}
\printbibliography[filter=example,title={Carti}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I found the filter on biblatex.pdf p. 100. I'll use it to generate more granular filters